# How to print elements of particular index in list in python?

Tags: python, list, indexing

Suppose I have list as `lists=[1,2,3,3,4,43]`
 
now i want to access 5 index element from the above list how can i do that?
I Tried sorting the list

```
lists.sort()
z=len(lists)
lists.index(z-1)
```

on trying to get 5th item i.e 4 it says value not in list.
how can I do that?

Comment: Maybe `lists[5]`?

Comment: it says value not in list

Comment: @NavaRajPokharel Read Alexander Lekontsev's comment more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the 5th index you should do: ‘list[4]’

What you tried ‘list.index(6-1)’ will return the index of the first value that equals 5

Answer (score 1):

```
lists.index(z-1)
```

> index() is an inbuilt function in Python, which searches for given
>   element from start of the list and returns the lowest index where the
>   element appears.

In your case z=6 and z-1=5, as 5 is not present in the list it returns

> ValueError: 5 is not in list

To get value use following

> lists[z-1]

it will return the value at the given index ie. value at z-1 index